# Connecting OPC UA Client to Flask Server

Tags: python, flask, opc-ua

I want to read out data from a PLC using OPC UA and build a Web-Interface with Flask to display and write data to the PLC. The OPC UA Server is running on the PLC, the OPC UA Client is running my computer (opcua-asyncio) - all this works just fine. The Web-Interface also works fine, getting and posting data to the Flask Server (running on the same computer as the OPC UA Client). However, I struggle to transfer the data from the OPC UA Client to the Flask-Server.

How can I get the data from my OPC UA Client to my Flask App? I´m really lost here since I´m pretty new to this subject, I hope anyone has an idea how to tackle this issue. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your post is a little unclear to me but I think I can take a guess. You mention a flask app writing data to the PLC so maybe I can imagine that the flask app lets you control the PLC and you are successfully writing data to the OPC-UA server.

At this point, I'm curious how you're verifying successful data being written to the OPC-UA server. I know that I would use [UAExpert](https://www.unified-automation.com/downloads.html) for this.

Now let's say everything checks out here.

> How can I get the data from my OPC UA Client to my Flask App?

It sounds like you want to make an endpoint with the OPC-UA client reading data from the server. Since you're using flask, then you would probably want to use a Python library like https://github.com/FreeOpcUa/opcua-asyncio

Hope that helps.